# How to upload file with AWS S3 - Angular 8

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, angular8

I've followed below link and trying to implement file upload feature in Angular 8.
https://medium.com/ramsatt/angular-7-upload-file-to-amazon-s3-bucket-ba27022bad54,

1. npm install aws-sdk --save

   1. npm install --save-dev @types/node
   2. Need to add "types": ["node"] to the tsconfig.app.json
   3. Add below lines in polyfills.js - Not sure where can I add in polyfills.js.

   if (typeof (window as any).global === 'undefined') { (window as any).global = window; }

After adding above line I'm getting error.

```
[error] C:\Users\admin\source\repos\polling-app-ui2\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:7
if (typeof (window as any).global === 'undefined') { (window as any).global = window; }

SyntaxError: (JS) **
```

> any

type assertion expression can only be used in .ts file**

Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in polyfills.ts not in js

Comment: This helped me - l was trying to solve this for an embarrassingly long time.